# NDSolve with NIntegrate

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, integral-equations

I'm new to *Mathematica* and I'm trying to use it to solve some equation like:

```
NDSolve[x'[t]+NIntegrate[x[tau],{tau,0,t}]==20,x,{t,0,10}]
```

But it keeps giving me some errors like:

> `tau = t is not a valid limit of integration.`

The actual problem is much more complicated and bigger. I would like to prefer not to take derivative on both sides.

Can anyone help? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, `NDSolve` doesn't solve integro-differential equations. Try taking the derivative of your equation and treating the differential equation as a second-order differential equation in `tau`, perhaps.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: In addition to @march 's comment, please remember that `NIntegrate` is a *numerical* integration routine. It needs its input to be explicitly a number; see [this FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/27951) for more details on this point.

Comment: @march thank you for your answer. I had that idea too. But the actual equations are much bigger and much more complicated. I don't think it is a great idea to take a derivative of my equations.

Comment: @MarcoB so actually it is not possible to solve this kind of equations with NDSolve?

Comment: I don't have much experience with integro - differential equations, but I suspect that you will have to rig something together yourself. For the numerical issue, in general you can define a function wrapper for your `NIntegrate` that only evaluates when given a numerical value of `t`. I don't know how to make that work within `NDSolve` though. A few examples of integro - differential problems have cropped up on the site already; you might get some inspiration by browsing the [`integral-equation` tag](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral-equation), if you haven't yet.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for your advice. I will review them.

Comment: @Jens I've read your post. It does quite good on normal functions. But actually in my equations it contains some interpolated function from a excel data. I'm not quite sure if Mathematica is capable of converting them into Laplace form.

Comment: If you post the actual problem with some example data, it may be easier to get a solution that is actually useful to you. It looks like you should pursue a discretized solution if your data are discretized to begin with. In particular, perhaps [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6974929/915703) is more useful.